# How to check if a table row exist with a trigger?

Tags: mysql, database

I want to check if a table row exist with a trigger. If it does then it does nothing, but if it doesnt exist it inserts a row.

Here is my current code I want to modify:

```
BEGIN
IF (NEW.counter >= 100) THEN
// check if a certain row exists in another table, if not, execute the beneath code
INSERT INTO tagCategories (name, counter) VALUES ('unnamed', NEW.counter);
UPDATE tagCategories2tagPairs SET tagCategoryId = LAST_INSERT_ID() WHERE tagPairId = OLD.id;
END IF;
END
```

Is there any good tutorials on this, teaching all functions you can use with a trigger (they don't look like the php functions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mysql trigger tutorial](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Triggers)

[CREATE TRIGGER Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html)

For the restrictions on behaviour allowed in Triggers, please see:

[D.1. Restrictions on Stored Routines, Triggers, and Events](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/mysql/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-program-restrictions.html)

To check if row exists and update it, otherwise insert a row if it does not exist, you can use the [`INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) statement, but within the restrictions for triggers mentioned in the above link.